# Jquery toggle with id

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I want to make the following example with toggle().

```js
function showforces(id)
{
       if( document.getElementById('combatforces'+id).style.display != 'block')
      {
        document.getElementById('combatforces'+id).style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('details'+id).innerHTML = 'Hide Forces';
      }
      else
      {
        document.getElementById('combatforces'+id).style.display = 'none';    
        document.getElementById('details'+id).innerHTML = 'Show Forces';
      }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="placecombatlarge" onclick="showforces(1)">
    <div  id="details1">
           Hide Forces
    </div>
    <div class="combatforces" id="combatforces1">
           Some Text
    </div>
</div>
```

but if i use

```js
function showforces(id)
    {
      $('combatforces'+id).toggle("slow", "swing");
    }
```

it doesnt work.
If i write

```js
function showforces(id)
    {
      $(combatforces1).toggle("slow", "swing");
    }
```

it works.

2nd problem: How do i change the details inner Html if its toggled or not?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: `$('#combatforces'+id)` you need to use [id selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

Comment: Thanks that works :D but i have no glue for the second problem :(

Answer (score 0):

```js
function showforces(id)
{
  if ($( '#combatforces'+id ).is( ":visible" ))
  {    
    document.getElementById('details'+id).innerHTML = 'Show Forces';
  }
  else
  {
    document.getElementById('details'+id).innerHTML = 'Hide Forces';
  }
  $('#combatforces'+id).toggle("slow", "swing");
}
```

its Working.  ;) 
Thanks for the Help (id selector) :)